# curl from docker on cluster node to master node

Tags: linux, docker, curl, containers, connection-refused

I have a cluster with one master node and 3 compute nodes.
A docker container on nodes 1 and 2 are able to "curl" to the master node.
However node-3 fails with "Connection refused"

- ping from container works
- ping and curl from container's host works (i.e. node-3 to master)
- shutting down docker0 worked for node-1 and 2. not for node-3 (https://serverfault.com/questions/642981/docker-containers-cant-resolve-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04-desktop-host)
- did not help: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
- firewalld is inactive on other nodes, so tried shutting it down on node-3 as well

what else can I look for?

UPDATE

thanks to @sxm1972, found this possibly unwanted entry while listing "docker network ls"

f49b6c9541d2        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local

how do I get rid of this?

deleted it using:
docker network rm f49b6c9541d2
sudo service docker restart

but that did not solve curl issue

UPDATE

Then looked at /etc/hosts
node3 contains an unexpected line:

```
192.168.1.1     079543e73dc7
```

the other nodes instead have an IP like  172.17.0.x

192.168.1.1  refers to master node's IP.

UPDATE

ifconfig on node1 and node2 host show 172.17.0.x for docker0 interface

ifconfig on node3 shows 192.168.x.x: this seems corrupt.

I might have inadvertently done something to node3 IP. How can I restore it?

UPDATE

Tried

```
ip link del docker0
sudo service docker restart
```

host docker0 IP still seems to be the  wrong one

SOLUTION

Thanks @sxm1972! the following worked:

```
sudo service docker stop
create/edit daemon.json from the link below setting bip to 172.17.0.1/16
ip link del docker0
sudo service docker restart
```

https://success.docker.com/article/How_do_I_configure_the_default_bridge_(docker0)_network_for_Docker_Engine_to_a_different_subnet

I can now "curl" from a container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PS C:\Users\smallya> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
857787541f21        bridge              bridge              local
f3de5219b77d        host                host                local
72ab4639a2dd        none                null                local
PS C:\Users\smallya> docker network inspect 857787541f21
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "857787541f210cb0912b3be240922810f007b149f200ae9fff5bdc111af14f14",
        "Created": "2018-02-09T14:31:17.0933179Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: @Tims, see answer above.

Comment: I see an extra docker_gwbridge...how can I delete it?

Comment: @Tims, you probably do not want to delete `docker_gwbridge` network. Here is a good explanation of docker networking
https://neuvector.com/blog/docker-swarm-container-networking/

Comment: the 3 nodes being identical and the other 2 nodes not having gwbridge made me to delete that bridge entry.  no harm so far. but I see something unusual in /etc/hosts. updated the original post  above. thanks

Comment: In the curl command are you using the master-node's IP address or the host-name? If you are using the host-name and the system depends on the host-name being resolvable via the hosts file, you should make an entry in the hosts file that maps the IP address of the master-node (172.17.0.x?) to the name of the master machine.

Can you post the output of your `docker network ls` and `docker network inspect` commands?

Comment: am using IP address. this seems to be an issue with host network config. I updated the post above. Is there a way to restore it?

Comment: Delete the docker0 bridge the following commands in order: `service docker stop`, `ip link del docker0`, `service docker start`. On restarting the docker daemon, the default docker0 network should get recreated.

https://superuser.com/questions/995373/remove-docker0-bridge

Comment: tried stopping the service before deleting the bridge as suggested. docker0 ip on host comes back to 192.168.x.x.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164966/discussion-between-sxm1972-and-tims).